# mpi4py groups can't create their own communicator noncollectively

Tags: mpi4py

I am trying to have groups of ranks create their own communicator in mpi4py. It does not appear as if this is possible, but the MPI-3 standard supports such operations.

Thank you

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the MPI-3 bindings in mpi4py-dev using:

git clone https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py.git

To build mpi4py-dev, you will need to have Cython available too.

http://cython.org/#download